# Performance ao desenhar uma imagem

Tags: c#, winforms, opengl, processamento-de-imagens

Atualmente uso o metodo DrawImage da classe Graphics. Porém, a velocidade de  desenho nos componentes é bem lenta. Como posso otimizar seu uso ?

Bibliotecas como MonoGame ou OpenTK podem oferecer maior desempenho nesse quesito ?

Eis um exemplo de código na sobrecarga do metodo OnPaint.

```
  if (m_IsThumbnail)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.DarkGray),
                new Point(dl + 3, dt + dh + 1 + j),
                new Point(dl + dw + 3, dt + dh + 1 + j));
            g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.DarkGray),
                new Point(dl + dw + 1 + j, dt + 3),
                new Point(dl + dw + 1 + j, dt + dh + 3));
        }

        XImage = dl;
        YImage = dt;

        g.DrawImage(m_Image, dl, dt, dw, dh); // lentidão.
```

Comment: Tá certo esse `if` sem as chaves (`{` e `}`)? Do jeito que está (sem as chaves) ele só inclui o laço `for` e talvez o restante (incluindo a chamada do seu `DrawImage`) esteja sendo executado desnessariamente a cada atualização da pintura... Além disso, como a sua chamada de `DrawImage` especifica tamanho, talvez o seu código esteja efetuando redimensionamento *a cada nova pintura*. Isso geralmente é custoso, e pode ser facilmente resolvido mantendo e reusando uma cópia da imagem previamente reduzida/aumentada.

Comment: Quanto ao if, está certo. No meu caso, o laço for é pouco custoso. O gargalo se concentra no metodo DrawImage. O método DrawImage no .NET é sempre lento. Ele usa o GDI+, visitei outros fóruns e outras pessoas tem o mesmo problema de lentidão ao utilizar esse método.

Comment: Ok. Bom, mesmo assim, deve valer a pena dar uma olhada se a sua chamada não está fazendo nenhum redimensionamento custoso. [Nesta resposta do SOEN](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11025428/2896619) tem outras dicas que também podem ser úteis. E se você chegou em uma alternativa que funciona melhor, eu sugiro postar uma resposta com ela pra eventualmente ajudar outros colegas no futuro. :)